# Firefox 3.5+ sqlite database for saved passwords

Tags: firefox, encryption, sqlite

My goal is to actually import thousands of hostname/login/passwords into the sqlite database "signons.sqlite" .  The table I believe I need is "moz_logins" .

For me this file is located at ~/.mozilla/RANDOM_STRING.default/signons.sqlite

I'm trying to figure out two things:

1)  What is the encryption method used for encryptedUsername and encryptedPassword ?

2)  What is the guid column/how are it's values created?

If the answer is somewhere along the lines of "You need to read the source code," that's fine, this task may be bigger than I imagined.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: by the way, i'm not doing anything nefarious, i already have legit access to these logins, but they are not stored in my mozilla db, so i have to do a lot of copy/paste on a daily basis

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked through http://kb.mozillazine.org/Password_Manager? There's a number of article links in it. The key should be in key3.db behind the master password, if needed. You'll need a way to handle the password.

Have a look at [this post about the encryption](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/37427-decrypt-firefox-passwords/page__p__10081796#entry10081796).

Guid is some kind of unique ID, generated somehow :)

There are some backup/decryption etc programs available. Instead of rtfs of FF, you might have a look at those.